# Concurrent users with nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am on a project with notification and messaging system between users. So, I started to learn Node.js and socket.io for real time web app. And its about to be finished. But I wanted to know how much concurrent users can socket.io handle. I would be using Amazon web services with auto scaling and elastic load balancing. And would start with *m1.medium* instance type, i.e vCPU = 1, ECU = 2, Memory = 3.75 GB

So, I would like to know, how much concurrent users, can it handle with only one *m1.medium* instance. If you could please help, would be highly grateful. Thank you!

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. Your best bet will be to test it. Further: Define your criteria / the word "handle". How many users until it gets "slow", "really slow", the server crashes...?

Comment: Hello! I prefer "slow".

Comment: It's called benchmarks, write one having your application logic and measure.

Answer (score 1):

As @reto said, it depends on multiple factors like:

- your hardware configuration and resources
- what you are doing/processing on the server
- if your system is optimized for concurrent connections

among others.

Check the following resources for suggestion on how achieve a high amount of concurrent conections (~200k - 1M).

- http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/
- http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/10/node-js-w250k-concurrent-connections/
- http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/wBpq3QuR0GQ
- http://blog.3rd-eden.com/post/5809079469/theoretical-node-js-real-time-performance